# beepr package error: unable to open WMM audio for output (2)

Tags: r, audio, beep

I wanted to play a beep sound in R using beepr package.
But when i run the `beep()` function I get the following error:

```
Warning message:
In value[[3L]](cond) :
  beep() could not play the sound due to the following error:
Error in play.default(x, rate, ...): unable to open WMM audio for output (2)
```

my R vesrion is 3.6.1. and the beepr version is 1.3